# Search MongoDB and for the same field I want to exclude some results

Tags: mongodb, search

I search for all the docs with status "request" but I want to exclude all the documents with the status "notInterested".

Here is the code:

```
getRelationships(){
    return Relationships.find({
        'whoId': Meteor.userId(),
        'status' : 'request',
        'status' : {$ne : 'notInterested'}
    });
}
```

Not working now, but I have no errors.

Comment: Not really clear what you want to do here; If you query for documents with status 'request' then mongo will return documents with that status and that includes documents that do not have the status "notInterested". Perhaps you meant another field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my below sample collection, there are three documents for "whoId" equals 123. Out of which two documents have status as "request" and one has "notInterested". The query has condition to include specific status (i.e. request) and exclude status (i.e. notInterested) as well.

The **$and** operator can be used to achieve this. If I understand your question correctly, this solution should resolve your problem.

**My Relationships collection data:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0d1d681b1cf15a897776"),
    "whoId" : "123",
    "status" : "request"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0d2f681b1cf15a897777"),
    "whoId" : "2321111",
    "status" : "notInterested"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0d5d681b1cf15a897778"),
    "whoId" : "123",
    "status" : "request"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0d65681b1cf15a897779"),
    "whoId" : "123",
    "status" : "notInterested"
}
```

**Query :-**

```
db.Relationships.find({whoId : '123', $and : [{status : 'request'}, {status : {$ne : 'notInterested'}}]})
```

**Result:-**
Please note that the status 'notInterested' has not been selected.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0d1d681b1cf15a897776"),
    "whoId" : "123",
    "status" : "request"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0d5d681b1cf15a897778"),
    "whoId" : "123",
    "status" : "request"
}
```